# Unable to format and use flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, format, google-chrome-os

A long time ago I had to use a flash drive to recover a Chromebook, a tool from Samsung/Google formatted the flash drive with the needed Chrome OS. Now that I need the flash drive for something else, I can't revert it. Any attempts for format it fail. When I look at it in Disk Management it looks like this:

[image]

I opened Diskpart from a command window and tried to recover it from there and that didn't work either. How can I reformat this flash drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you remove all the partitions, create a new partition, and then format it ?

If not then I would use the GParted LiveCD to run GParted to remove all the partitions and then try and create a vfat partition through GParted

Comment: That would be the problem, I don't have any spare DVDs so I cant use GParted, it won't let me remove or format any of the partitions :l [http://cl.ly/SYn3](http://cl.ly/SYn3) [http://cl.ly/SYLz](http://cl.ly/SYLz)
EDIT: *facepalm* I have blank CDs I can run GParted off of

Comment: Brilliant ! You're Welcome :)